What is the magnetic field created by a charged square rotating about its center
In a class on electromagnetism, a question came up where my answer was close to the prescribed answer but not exactly so. I used a different method from the one used in class, and I am not sure if it's right. Would appreciate it if someone could help out.
$\textbf{Question}$ -
Imagine four charged rods of length $l$ connected end to end to form a square. Now, this contraption is made to spin about the center of the square with an angular velocity $\omega$. The linear charge density of every rod is $\lambda$. What is the magnetic field produced by the spinning rods at the center of the square?
$\textbf{Method}$ -
When the square spins, its blur will be the torus shape, shown below. By basic geometry, the shape will have an inner radius of $l/2$ and an outer radius of $l/\sqrt2$. Now, if we take an arbitrary circle on this torus (represented in yellow), we see 8 points of the square are on the circle. Now, let each of the each points have a charge of $di$.
The formula for magnetic field in the center of a circular wire of radius $r$ with a current of $i$ flowing through it is $\mu_oi/2r$. Now, since each point has a charge of $di$ and the angular speed is $\omega$, the current for each circle ($i$), is
$\frac{8.di.\omega}{2\pi}$.
And finally, $di$ = $\lambda dx$
Now if we integrate many such rings, we should get the final magnetic field produced by the square at its center.
$\int\limits_{a/2}^{a/\sqrt2}\frac{\mu_o8\lambda dx\omega}{4 \pi x}$
Now, this comes out to - $\frac{2\mu_o\lambda\omega \ln\sqrt2}{\pi}$
However, the answer given in the class was $\frac{2 \mu_o \lambda \omega \ln(\sqrt2+1)}{\pi}$
Is there something wrong with my approach.


I'd evaluate the electric charge distribution before this "blur" argument, if you really want to use it (it sounds reasonable, but I'm not sure 100% you can)

If you take a yellow circle halfway between the two blue circles, you can see that more of the white line is inside the yellow than outside. You need to make sure your blur method doesn't assume equal amounts of white line at each radius.

btw what did you use for making the visualization here?

@SidharthGhoshal it's just PowerPoint lol

Short Answer:
Your error lies in the fact that the differential length $\mbox{d} x$ and the change in radius $\mbox{d} r$ are not the same. You have confused these two quantities in your integral. Using geometric relationships, we can derive the correct relationship between them.

Detailed explanation:

As you mentioned, we only need to consider one-eighth of the square, which means taking half of one side, as shown in the figure. The length of this side is $l/2$. The uniformly charged rod $AB$ rotates in the plane with an angular velocity $\omega$, and its distance to the origin is $|OB|=l/2$. Drawing a circle centered at the origin with radius $r$ intersects the rod at point $C$. Let $x=|BC|$.
Using the Pythagorean theorem, we get $x=\sqrt{r^2-l^2/4}$. Therefore, when the radius changes by $\mbox{d} r$, the length of the rod swept by the arc changes by
$$
\mbox{d}x = \frac{r \mbox{d}r}{\sqrt{r^2-l^2/4}}.
$$
The charge on this segment of the rod is
$$
\mbox{d} q = \lambda \mbox d x
$$
where $\lambda$ is the charge density. This charge moves in a circular motion with angular velocity $\omega$, creating an equivalent current of
$$
\mbox{d} i = \frac{\mbox{d} q}{2\pi/\omega}.
$$
The magnetic field at the origin due to this current segment is
$$
\mbox dB = \frac{\mu_0 \mbox di}{2r}.
$$
Thus, the total magnetic field is
$$
\begin{aligned}
B &= \int_{r=l/2}^{r=l/\sqrt{2}} \mbox dB\\
& = \frac{\mu_0 \lambda \omega}{4\pi} \int_{l/2}^{l/\sqrt{2}} \frac{\mbox d r}{\sqrt{r^2-l^2/4}}\\
& = \frac{\mu_0 \lambda \omega \ln(\sqrt{2}+1)}{4\pi}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Multiplying this result by 8 gives the correct answer.
